# SAS Proc Compare Out Dataset Structure

Tags: sas, compare

proc compare outputs these results & I want an outputted SAS data set that has this exact same structure

[image]

The closest I can achieve is this but you can see my ID variable is in there twice:

```
proc compare base= b compare=c out= discordant outnoequal outbase outcomp;
    id bridge_recip_id;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try using PROC TRANSPOSE?

Comment: Please share some example data (as text, not as pictures).

Answer (score 1):

Just use PROC TRANSPOSE.  Since you didn't post any data let's make up some datasets to compare.

```
data class changed;
  set sashelp.class;
  output class;
  age = age + mod(_n_,3);
  output changed;
run;
```

Now we can generate an output dataset with just the differences. And then use PROC TRANSPOSE to convert it from TALL to WIDE format.

```
proc compare noprint base=class compare=changed
  out=tall outnoequal outbase outcomp outdif outpercent
;
  id name;
  var age;
run;

proc transpose data=tall out=wide ;
  by _obs_ name;
  id _type_;
  var age;
run;

proc print;
  by _name_;
run;
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I think you're right that proc transpose is the only way to get what i want. bummer though, i find transposing in SAS to be confusing. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting way to do this that doesn't go through `PROC TRANSPOSE` and doesn't just create this from scratch... `ods output`.  I'm not sure I recommend actually doing this, but for some this might be easier than the alternatives.

```
data class_changed;
  set sashelp.class;
  age = age + mod(_n_,3);
run;

ods trace on;
ods output CompareDifferences=diffs;
proc compare base=sashelp.class compare=class_changed;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Unfortunately, PROC COMPARE has the absolute worst `ODS OUTPUT` of any proc I've seen that has any output at all... but it is parseable, if you want to go to the trouble, using SCAN or SUBSTR or such.  And if you're just putting it out somewhere else, it would work fine for that!